# OGG-01921 rprim01.prm: Missing GETBEFORECOLS with conflict detection enabled in target table

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I am configuring a CDR test env.I have enabled supplemental logging on the source table.Still the replicat process in complaining about before images not present.Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Database should be in archive mode and force logging mode.